# Java + Selenium + log4j: How to write generic function for Logging in pagefactory? Possible?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, page-objects, logs

I have written a selenium framework using `page object` design pattern. To make it better I am also using `PageFactory`.
Example:

**BasePage.java**

```
@FindBy(xpath= FinalLocators.userName)
WebElement uname;

@FindBy(xpath= FinalLocators.userpass)
WebElement userpwd;

sendkeys.uname("johndoe");
sendkeys.userpwd("kitty");
```

**FinalLocators.java**

```
public static final String userName=//input[text()='username']
public static final String userpass=//input[text()='password']
```

Now, I want loggers (`log4j`) to give me:

Element `uname` not found. I want the `WebElement` name to be in logs not the `xpath` declared in `FinalLocators`.

**Edit:**
In non `PageFactory` projects it is written something like this:

```
public void sendData(String xpathKey){
    try{            
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(xpathKey))).sendKeys("abc");
    logger.info("Found "+xpathKey);
    }catch(Exception e){
    logger.info("wait started for "+xpathKey);

            }
    
}
```

But in `PageFactory` based framework how to write such a generic function?

Comment: Could you please explain your question? what exactly you want? You have to use Log4j in your script right?

Comment: You would need to implement your own PageFactory with your own implementation of FieldDecorator interface that decorates original DefaultFieldDecorator: delegates calles to it and logs possible problems.

Comment: How ????????????????

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with you **@dzieciou**. I have **experienced that, delegates might be the culprit.**

It would be great if one could suggest us the actual solution for generic logging with BasePage.java and FinalLocators.java

**@paul** - Below middle way/**workaround I found and working well** for me:

- **Remove** or stop using **FinalLocators.java** [ explanation:Something is not working fine with using both FieldDacorator and FinalLocators ]
- **Instead of initializing final string** under FinalLocators.java, **shift those directly in BasePage.java**
- **Basic code snippet**

> @FindBy(xpath="//input[text()='username']")
>
> WebElement uname;
>
> @FindBy(xpath="//input[text()='password']")
>
> WebElement userpwd;

// Here you can **directly get access to your actual defined Element** under own PageFactory

> sendkeys.uname("johndoe");
>
> sendkeys.userpwd("kitty");

Using this I am able to fine Element uname in log. Give a Try !